# Laravel: Getting inconsistent results from API

Tags: php, laravel

I have a items endpoint that paginates items.  I've noticed that the items returned don't seem to be consistent each time I hit the endpoint.  I'm starting to wonder if there's something wrong the query I am using but can't seem to see what the issue would be:

```
$paginator = Items::whereNull('time_destroyed')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->selectRaw('MAX(id) as id, MAX(created_at) as created_time, product_id')
    ->groupBy('product_id', 'created_at')
    ->paginate($default);

$data = $paginator->toArray();

$ids = $paginator->pluck('id')->toArray();

$posts = Items::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
$posts->load('product.elbin', 'product.inventoryQuantity', 'product.inventory');

$data['data'] = $posts->toArray();

return response($data, 200)->withHeaders(cache_header('posts posts-page-'.$request->input('page'), 10));
```

Comment: In what way are they inconsistent?

Comment: @ceejayoz for example, page2 may have an item that already appeared in page1 or sometimes an item would not be in the pagination results at all

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.